# Autostart C application in Ubuntu before to login

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'd like to automatically start a C application when i power up my Ubuntu.

I know that i can use app start from system menu in order to choose what application has to start after the login.

The problem is that i do not need to use the X server, so i do not want to log in my desktop.

I just want to autostart my C program without typing any key and without use my Desktop.
I want to press the power on button and do nothing else to start the C program which has to start automatically.

Is it possible?

Can this document help me?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto

Comment: yes, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Installing_custom_init-scripts in particular

Comment: Stack overflow is for programming questions...

Comment: Why do you always mention C? e language a program is written in is completely irrelevant for how it is started...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that document looks good. It talks about what I was going to say, use init scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the command to run in your `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 0):

Use Supervisor, an effective program that manages and logs the startup applications with arguments.
Learn more from `http://supervisord.org/running.html` and 
(Follow the installation instruction there and create conf file at
/etc/supervisord/conf.d/{PROGRAM_NAME}.conf and add the conf code.

Here is the code,

```
[program:{PROGRAM_NAME}]
command=/usr/bin/{PROGRAM_NAME} -arg1 -arg2
autostart=true  
autorestart=true  
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/{PROGRAM_NAME}.err.log  
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/{PROGRAM_NAME}.out.log  

supervisorctl reload
```